# Sending my html email

Tags: php, css, email

I know there is lots of information everywhere about this subject but I seem to be going around in circles and would greatly appreciate any help. I am trying to send a simple html email with some inline css. The email does not seem to arrive...

```
<?php
// Email the user their activation link
        $to = "name@website.com";                            
        $from = "me@website.com";
        $subject = 'Test HTML Email';

$headers = "";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<div style="padding:10px; background:#000; font-size:46px; font-weight: 900; color:#fff; ">
        My Website
      </div>
      <div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px; background:#DCDCDC  ; ">
        This is a message sent from my website
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">Login in to your account</a>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>';

mail($to, $subject,  $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Try: $isMailed = mail($to, $subject,  $message, $headers); echo $isMailed; Does this return true or false? And add $headers .= "From: yourmail.com \r\n"; Just saw it, but ben was ahead of me..

Comment: The sender is not defined.

Comment: I tend to recommend against using `mail()` and just use a decent library (PHPMailer, SwiftMailer). That will protect against security problems too, such as header injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite this code:

```
$headers = "";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

to this:

```
$headers = "";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "To: ". $to. "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ". $from;
```

Comment: Many thanks, this was the first thing I tried and it worked straight away. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
$headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```